# Magento 2 get Area Code

Tags: magento2, plugin

I'm trying to determine on a plugin if the request comes from admin or for frontend.
I had to make a plugin for Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface, and in my plugin I need to detect the area code on my aroundGetValue function.
I'm trying this:

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$area = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$areaCode= $area->getAreaCode();
```

But when I deploy my code I'm getting this error:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Area code is not set
```

I don't know how to check at that level if the request comes from admin or for frontend.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

On your construct, put:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\State $state)
{
   $state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
}
```

And try again

Comment: Hi Max! If I set the area code, then on the function where I need to get the area code I will get the area code that I setted on the construct, that won't be the real one

Comment: Ah ok, if you change setAreaCode for getAreaCode or you can check current url

Comment: not advisable to set area code in construct as it can break a lot of things, do it somewhere else in the class with a try catch if you need to check if its set first